# ASP.NET dynamically adding UserControl to PlaceHolder, not fire Click Event, only Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, master-pages, placeholder

In my ASP.Net page I have PlaceHolder and Button. When user click on this button, I add some UserControls from my Interface method getControl to the PlaceHolder. Code:

```
    protected void ActionBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (provider != null)
        {
            actualObject = (PlaceHolder)provider.getControl();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(actualObject);
        }
    }
```

Method getControl:

```
    public object getControl()
    {
        ph = new PlaceHolder();

        exportInbBtn = new Button();
        exportInbBtn.Text = "Export Inventury";
        exportInbBtn.Click += new EventHandler(myButton_ServerClick);
        ph.Controls.Add(exportInbBtn);
        exportInbBtn.ID = "exportInbBtn";

        return ph;
    }
```

Methods Page_Load and Page_Init in ASP page are empty. Problem is, when the user click at the button exportInbBtn (with text: "Export Inventury"), the click event myButton_ServerClick will not rise. Only web page refresh. I ready some answers, but I can´t figure how easily solve this problem.

Comment: There is a page.LoadControl: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7908/Dynamically-Loading-User-Control-on-a-Webform-usin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you fire *myButton_ServerClick* event, postback is invoked and ASP.Net want to fire called event, but your control is not added to the page, that's why ASP.Net ignore this event.

After postback and before event to be fired, you must add your control again and after them, event will be invoked.

**Update**

Something like this

Page:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" Text="Add control" OnClick="btnTest_Click"/>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="result"></asp:Label>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="controlLoaded"/>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phTest"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (controlLoaded.Value == "1")
        {
            AddControl();
        }
    }

    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddControl();
    }

    protected void myButton_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = "OK";
    }

    public object getControl()
    {
        var ph = new PlaceHolder();

        var exportInbBtn = new Button();
        exportInbBtn.Text = "Export Inventury";
        exportInbBtn.Click += new EventHandler(myButton_ServerClick);
        ph.Controls.Add(exportInbBtn);
        exportInbBtn.ID = "exportInbBtn";

        return ph;
    }

    private void AddControl()
    {
        var actualObject = (PlaceHolder)getControl();
        phTest.Controls.Add(actualObject);
        controlLoaded.Value = "1";
    }
```

Comment: What do you think "After postback and before event to be fired"? Can you write some code example, where I have to add control?

Answer (score 4):

Please note that UserControls are added by the below method - 
// First create the instance of user control
var control  = Page.LoadControl("~/folder1/UserControl1.ascx")

// Now add this control to placeholder as - placeHolder1.Controls.Add(control);

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**page.aspx**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

**page.aspx.vb**

```
Private Sub CreateControl()
    Dim vw As Control
    vw = CType(LoadControl("~/View01.ascx"), View01)
    vw.ID = "View_Dyn"
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear()
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(vw)
End Sub
```

**Recreate it every postback**

```
Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    CreateControl()
End Sub
```